# HTML5 Flowplayer

Tags: files

I'm working with videos using flowplayer. My video plays in a Flash player, but I want it to be in HTML5. How do I play flowplayer videos in HTML5?

Answer (score 1):

[Video.js](https://drupal.org/project/videojs)

> Is a HTML5-based video player with a built-in Flash fallback for older
>   browsers. This means that videos can be played on nearly all devices
>   and operating systems, provided the right codecs are used.

This module is a support module for Video.js. It doesn't contain Video.js itself, but integrates it with the File, Link and Video modules after you've installed it.

or

**[Projekktor](https://drupal.org/project/projekktor)** (HTML5 Video Player) with **flash support**

> A free, open source (GPL) HTML5 based video player written in
>   Javascript. It solves cross browser and compatibility issues, adds eye
>   candy and provides extremely powerful non standard features.

Check Out the [DEMO](http://www.lunarclips.com/)

```
HTML5 Native Video (with flash fallback)

File extension  Type
.ogv    video/ogg
.webm   video/webm
.ogg    video/ogg
.anx    video/ogg
.mp4    video/mp4

Flash Video

File extension  Type
.flv    video/x-flv
.flv    video/flv
.mp4    video/mp4
.mov    video/quicktime
.m4v    video/mp4
```

Comment: No i need HTML5 Flash Player?

Comment: I updated my answer